# How to do this with Vue SCRIPT SETUP

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I am using this lib simple-vue-camera. Got it to work properly,but i wish I could use it with script setup. I cant access the snapshot method of the camera..

The problem i guess is in the 'const cameraComponent = this.$refs.camera' where I cant access the Camera component via refs, and get its snapshot method.

Here is the code working with regular composition API:

```html
<template>
    <q-dialog ref="dialogRef" @hide="onDialogHide">
        <q-card class="column q-dialog-plugin">
            <div class="colunm">
                <ModalBar :icon="'mdi-camera'" :title="$t('global.camera')" class="col" @close="onCancelClick" />
                <q-separator />
                <div>
                    <camera v-if="!fotoTirada" ref="camera" :resolution="{ width: 400, height: 400 }" autoplay></camera>
                    <img v-else :src="imageUrl" />
                </div>
                <q-separator />
                <q-card-actions class="flex justify-between">
                    <q-btn color="secondary-2" label="Cancelar" @click="onDialogHide" />
                    <div>
                        <q-btn v-if="!fotoTirada" color="primary" label="Capturar" @click="takeSnapshot" />
                        <q-btn v-if="fotoTirada" label="Tirar outra foto" @click="fotoTirada = false" />
                        <q-btn v-if="fotoTirada" color="primary" label="Salvar" @click="onOKClick(imageUrl)" />
                    </div>
                </q-card-actions>
            </div>
        </q-card>
    </q-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import Camera from "simple-vue-camera";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useDialogPluginComponent } from 'quasar'
import ModalBar from "components/ModalBar.vue";

export default defineComponent({

    components: {
        Camera,
        ModalBar
    },

    emits: [
        ...useDialogPluginComponent.emits
    ],

    setup() {
        const { dialogRef, onDialogHide, onDialogOK, onDialogCancel } = useDialogPluginComponent()

        return {
            dialogRef,
            onDialogHide,
            onOKClick(imageUrl) {
                onDialogOK(imageUrl)
            },
            onCancelClick: onDialogCancel
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            imageUrl: null,
            fotoTirada: null,
        };
    },

    methods: {
        async takeSnapshot() {
            const cameraComponent = this.$refs.camera;
            const blob = await cameraComponent.snapshot({ width: 400, height: 400 });
            this.imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", blob);
            this.fotoTirada = true;
        },
    },

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's normal to use, try to use camera.value, see this example

```
<script setup>
import Camera from "simple-vue-camera";
import { ref, defineExpose } from "vue";
import { useDialogPluginComponent } from 'quasar'
import ModalBar from "components/ModalBar.vue";

const { dialogRef, onDialogHide, onDialogOK, onDialogCancel } = useDialogPluginComponent()

const camera = ref(null)
const imageUrl = ref(null)
const photoTaken = ref(false)

const onOKClick = (imageUrl) => {
  onDialogOK(imageUrl)
}

const onCancelClick = () => {
  onDialogCancel()
}

const takeSnapshot = async () => {
  const cameraComponent = camera.value;
  const blob = await cameraComponent.snapshot({ width: 400, height: 400 });
  imageUrl.value = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", blob);
  photoTaken.value = true;
}

defineExpose({
  dialogRef,
  onDialogHide,
  onOKClick,
  onCancelClick,
  camera,
  imageUrl,
  photoTaken,
  takeSnapshot
})
</script>
```

Comment: Yeahh. thank you, that worked. I dont understand it though,
How am I able to get the snapshot method if I didnt say that the camera ref is bonded to the imported Camera. Can you explain that if possible?